# Add a directory to clickonce

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a directory and its files to visual studio keeping the root dir. I did this with the below piece of XML on my `.csproj` file but this does add all its files to solution explorer but exclude the root. The file are variable and I don't want to hard code them add manually. That's why I'm looking for an automated solution.

How do I fix this?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="bin\x86\release\myFolder\**\*">
      <Visible>true</Visible>
      <Link>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
```

I would like to include this directory (and not only its files) in ClickOnce publishing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't think of any automatic way to created the folder and make the solutin explorer aware of this files. So I created the folder on right click on project -> add folder. Unloaded the project and edited the piece of XML which add the directory I've created to solution explorer to this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="foo\*.*">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Visible>True</Visible>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now solution explorer is aware of that files and so does clickonce. The files get properly in the `app.publish` folder

NOTE: On this project, the foo files came from another folder (external C++'s binary output folder). They're copyed at post-build time. The folder name is sort of hard-coded (I need to chage them manually on the VS solution explorer, on the .csproj file and in the xcopy command-line on post-build) cause I didn't find any other way to do that.

Comment: seems like an easy way to accomplish what you needed.

Comment: @ShyamalDesai The only I managed to do that, I'm using since then.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Target Name="AddGeneratedFiles" AfterTargets="SOMETASK">
    <CreateItem Include="*.cpp">
      <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="ClCompile" />
    </CreateItem>
  </Target>
```

Comment: I get same behavior. This must be put right before the end of </Project> right?